# How do I add and use MNIST in Julia 1.6.6?

Tags: julia, mnist

The code for Mohammad Nauman's excellent book shows this (for Julia 1.5.3):

```
using Flux, Statistics 
using Flux.Data.MNIST
using Flux: onehotbatch
```

Which fails under Julai 1.6.6 with

```
UndefVarError: MNIST not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [2] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1116
```

So I try

```
] add MNIST
```

which gives

```
The following package names could not be resolved:
 * MNIST (not found in project, manifest or registry)
```

If I try

```
using MNIST
```

it gives

```
ArgumentError: Package MNIST not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("MNIST")` to install the MNIST package.
```

If I then try the recommended

```
import Pkg; Pkg.add("MNIST")
```

it gives

```
The following package names could not be resolved:
 * MNIST (not found in project, manifest or registry)
```

The author's code also gives the same error under 1.6.6.

How can I use MNIST under Julia 1.6.6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MNIST dataset is available from the [MLDatasets.jl package](https://github.com/JuliaML/MLDatasets.jl).

A lot of information is available in the package documentation: [MNIST](https://juliaml.github.io/MLDatasets.jl/stable/datasets/MNIST/).

```
]add MLDatasets
```

```
using MLDatasets

# load training set
train_x, train_y = MNIST.traindata()

# load test set
test_x,  test_y  = MNIST.testdata()
```

---

To expand on the above and add some background information. I don't have the book so I can't check exactly what version of Flux is used but it is some version prior to v0.12.0 which is when the datasets were removed ([see commit b78cd76](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/commit/b78cd76faa31b23cc0c9f7fd462c5e32f0187a7a)) in favor of MLDatasets ([relevant PR](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/pull/1377)). Of course having a different Julia version does not prevent you from installing an older version of Flux. I would not recommend opting for an older version of Flux if this is the only issue you're facing. Up to date tutorials will be using MLDatasets and the Julia community in general tends to converge on a single package for a particular purpose.

To clarify the example above:

where you would before do:

```
train_x = MNIST.images(:train)
train_y = MNIST.labels(:train)

test_x = MNIST.images(:train)
test_y = MNIST.labels(:train)
```

you would now instead use the code above. The labels are identical in the two cases:

```
julia> train_x, train_y = MLDatasets.MNIST.traindata();

julia> Data.MNIST.labels(:train) == train_y
true
```

However, `Flux.Data.MNIST.images(:train)` returns a `Vector` of images (28x28 matrices with `eltype` `Gray{N0f8}`) while MLDatasets returns (more or less) a 3D tensor (28x28x60000). To get data identical to the one in Flux.Data.MNIST we need to split up the matrices of the tensor, turn them into images (`Gray` elements), and transpose them.

```
julia> using ImageCore
julia> map(transpose, eachslice(Gray.(train_x); dims=3)) == Data.MNIST.images(:train)
true
```

If you decide that you prefer using an older version of Flux you could try v0.12.2 - v0.12.10. They are compatible with your Julia version and "still" have `Flux.Data.MNIST` (the datasets were added back but marked as deprecated):

```
pkg> add Flux#v0.12.10
```

Comment: They must have completely changed the API as well.  MNIST.images() doesn't exist any longer.

Comment: A complete example is here: https://sylvaticus.github.io/SPMLJ/stable/04_-_NN_-_Neural_Networks/0402_-_Implementation_of_neural_networks_workflows.html#Convolutional-neural-networks

Comment: The only API calls you have there are .traindata and .testdata.  I need an example of using readimageheader and readimages.

Comment: @DeanSchulze I've added some information to the answer. If you need something very specific perhaps you could write a new question with more information. As I've written in the answer I don't have access to the book so I can't look up the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MLDatasets using the following:

```
using Flux
using Flux: Data.DataLoader
using Flux: onehotbatch, onecold, crossentropy
using Flux: @epochs
using Statistics
using MLDatasets
# Load the data
x_train, y_train = MLDatasets.MNIST.traindata()
x_valid, y_valid = MLDatasets.MNIST.testdata()
# Add the channel layer
x_train = Flux.unsqueeze(x_train, 3)
x_valid = Flux.unsqueeze(x_valid, 3)
# Encode labels
y_train = onehotbatch(y_train, 0:9)
y_valid = onehotbatch(y_valid, 0:9)
# Create the full dataset
train_data = DataLoader(x_train, y_train, batchsize=128)
```

(Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-with-julia-flux-jl-story-7544c99728ca)

However, the discussion I have in the book/course about the shapes would not match since the structure of data has changed in MLDatasets package. If you want to follow that discussion in earnest, I suggest installing the version I'm using over there. You can make sense of it yourself too if you're willing to put in the time.

Disclaimer: I'm the author mentioned in the original post.